# How do I send SignalR messages from within an existing Azure function without adding a new Azure function? Can it be done?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

C# learner here. I hope the question makes sense, but if not, read on!

I have an existing Azure function setup (.NET 6) that, when it receives a http trigger, will trigger an orchestrator function that uses an activity trigger to start a function that will copy all messages from an Azure Storage Queue to A Cosmos DB (the QueueStore function below). I would like to also send each of the messages to a client using SignalR via an existing SignalR Service and Hub, also in Azure.

There is a lot of documentation on creating the SignalR and negotiate functions but how do I send a message from within my already called function?

The code for the copy function is below. I'm sure those more experienced developers will spot lots of ways I can optimise things, but I am honestly just happy getting it to work at this stage. As it currently stands, the function works as expected and required but I want to add the SignalR functionality at the commented location in the code.

How can I best go about this?

```
[FunctionName(nameof(QueueStore))]
public static async Task<string> QueueStore([ActivityTrigger] QueueName queue, ILogger log)
{
// Get the connection string
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QueueStorage");

try
{
    CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("some info here");
    Database database = client.GetDatabase("database");
    bool databaseExists = true;
    try
    {
        var response = await database.ReadAsync();
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        if (ex.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.NotFound))
        {
            // Does not exist
            databaseExists = false;
        }
    }

    //Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to manipulate the queue
    QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queue.Name);
    QueueProperties properties = await queueClient.GetPropertiesAsync();

    bool appDisconnected = false;

    //string message = "Stored messages ";
    if (queueClient.Exists() && databaseExists)
    {
                
        Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(id: queue.Name,
            partitionKeyPath: "/partKey", //name of the json var we want as partition key
            throughput: 400
        );

        while (appDisconnected == false)
        {
            if (queueClient.GetProperties().Value.ApproximateMessagesCount == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            else
            {
                QueueMessage[] retrievedMessage = await queueClient.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1);

                var fd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject(retrievedMessage[0].Body.ToString());

                if (!fd.ContainsKey("disconnected"))
                {


                    PartitionKey partKey = new PartitionKey(queue.PartKey);
                    // save to db

                    var createdItem = await container.CreateItemAsync<JObject>(
                        item: fd,
                        partitionKey: partKey);

                    //######## HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SEND THE fd Object via SignalR
                            
            //######## I have tried many different things but nothing works                         
                    
                    await queueClient.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage[0].MessageId,
                        retrievedMessage[0].PopReceipt);
                }
                else
                {
                    appDisconnected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return "Copied all Items";
    }
    else
    {
        return $"The queue peek didn't work because I can't find the queue:-(";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

}

I have tried calling a SignalR function from the orchestrator but that is adding a function outside the copy function process and would mean duplicating the calls to the queue and doesn't really help. I haven't seen any way to just send a SignalR message from the location indicated in the code. I have also tried standard .Net SignalR code, but can find no examples that have worked for me. Any pointers and suggestions would be greatly received.

Can this be done? Should I just create an entirely new function app and make a http call to that?

Trying to make my intended version of this has been causing me a lot of issues and, having not found any documentation on it, I may be architecting things wrong but thought I would ask here for any suggestions before re-writing everything as I am rather time-limited to work on this app.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have tried adding an example Azure SignalR Function called by the orchestrator and also called from the commented area of the code and I have tried examples from the .NET documentation and the SignalR Azure Functions examples. I was hoping that there were examples of this or a tutorial somewhere I could follow but it seems like I'm trying to do something no one else has done, which might mean I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely... :-(

Comment: Try an output trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: @PeterBons I got it working, thanks for your help! I will post a few pointers here that might help others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to Peter for making me think twice about my question.

I over complicated things. All that is needed to broadcast a message is the output binding added to the code (with the correct hub name), the connection string for the Azure Signalr service and the CLIENT method name.

As I had an existing web app as a hub, I used the Azure SignalR Service in "Default" mode.

Add the line

```
[SignalR(HubName = "NameOfYourHub")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages
```

to any other bindings (eg the trigger binding). Then make sure the

```
"AzureSignalRConnectionString":"<your SignalR connection string>"
```

is in your local.settings.json under the "Values" category and/or the application settings in Azure.

Finally, in my case, as I was just broadcasting to clients I added the name of the client method that deals with and displays the data in the indicated location:

```
signalRMessages.AddAsync(
    new SignalRMessage
    {
        Target = "nameOfClientMethod",
        Arguments = new [] { messageAsString }
    });
```

I was able to use the LiveTrace functionality of the Azure SignalR service to make sure that all clients were connecting to the correct hub name and to trace the messages being sent to the clients. I recommend it for trouble shooting SignalR.